# Google Map and Driving directions in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I have this code working by itself, without bootstrap. For some reason I cannot figure it out yet, when I include the js by script tag in the contact.html page, the page does not render the map. I know that sometimes bootstrap is very tricky.
I have moved my script after and before the head tag and does not work still. I have checked my script against reference book that I have and I cannot find anything to change that might help. I need advice of any of you guru bootstrap people.  Probably will be something very simple that I have overlooked. I am including the map in line #19 through #23. Bellow will be my code....

```
  <!-- Page Heading/Breadcrumbs -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Contact
          <small>Mission Link</small>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="active">Contact</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

      <!-- Content Row -->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Map Column -->
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div id="map"></div>
            <div id="directions"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Contact Details Column -->
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h3>Contact Details</h3>
          <p>
            One University Park Dr.<br>Nashville, TN 370204<br>
          </p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
            <abbr title="Phone">P</abbr>: (123) 456-7890</p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
            <abbr title="Email">E</abbr>: <a href="mailto:info@missionlink.org">info@missionlink.org</a>
          </p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
            <abbr title="Hours">H</abbr>: Monday - Friday / 9:00 AM to 5:00 PM</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
```

##############JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var markers = [];
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.1053976, -86.8000707);
  var mapOptions = {
        zoom     : 8, 
        center   : myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
  var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map').get(0), mapOptions);

  var listener = 
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.LatLng, map: map});
    markers.push(marker);
    if (markers.length > 1) {
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
        var marker1 = markers[0];
        var marker2 = markers[1];
        var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
        directionsRenderer.setPanel($('#directions').get(0));
        var request = {
            origin     : marker1.getPosition(),
            destination: marker2.getPosition(),
            travelMode : google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: As it is(without any CSS) the map doesn't have a size/height

Comment: Oh thank you.  I got my map displayed. Now my markers are not working.  I am trying to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

1. the event-property which returns the clicked coordinate is `latLng` not `LatLng`

   ```
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.latLng, map: map});
   ```
2. you must call the route-method of the DirectionsService to request a direction

   ```
       directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
        }
       });
   ```

---

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  'use strict';
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var markers = [];
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.1053976, -86.8000707);
  var mapOptions = {
        zoom     : 8, 
        center   : myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
  var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map').get(0), mapOptions);

  var listener = 
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.latLng, map: map});
    markers.push(marker);
    if (markers.length > 1) {
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
        var marker1 = markers[0];
        var marker2 = markers[1];
        var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
        directionsRenderer.setPanel($('#directions').get(0));
        var request = {
            origin     : marker1.getPosition(),
            destination: marker2.getPosition(),
            travelMode : google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
          directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
      markers[0].setMap(null);
      markers[1].setMap(null);
    }
  });

    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,body,#map{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```